# C# - Compress files and folders in gzip

Tags: c#, file, compression, gzip, rar

i need to create a compressed file (rar, gz, or other witch supports large files and large compressed file). I need to create folders and add files separated by folders.
Example: I have a folders structure like this

```
Folder 1
  Folder 1.1
  Folder 1.2
  Folder 1.3
Folder 2
  Folder 2.1
    Folder 2.1.1
```

in each folder i have some files.
I need to replicate the structure in a compressed file
The zip compress aparently has some limitations, as file size and compressed file size.
I have tried with GZipStream, but i not discovered how to create folders inside gz file.

Comment: gzip is a bytestream compressor, it does not support folders. You need to use something like zip.

Comment: the compression may be in tar.gz or another, not necessarily gzip. Zip may be problematic because has limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GZIP can only compress streams (hence the name GZip*Stream*). That's why gzip is often used together with tar (like .tar.gz files), where tar creates an archive out of the folder structure and gzip compresses that archive.

If you can't use either ZipArchive or ZipFile (in `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`) for your purposes, your best bet would be an external library/package, like [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) or [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress).

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try SharpCompress